# Displaying subcategories instead of products 2.1

Tags: magento2, navigation

I am fairly new to Magento, and am having trouble figuring out what I need to add to do this. I have looked all over for this, but can not find a solution that shows how to do this for magento 2. I am looking for how to create a module that displays all of the subcategories of the category clicked. If there are no more subcategories, then I want to display the products for that category.

I have tried making blocks in the admin panel, and attaching these blocks to the product category. I would really like to just create a module that does this for me though.

Answer (score 2):

You need to customized the category in the theme folder use the
following file structure and update the following code

```
/app/design/frontend/<vendor>/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/category

products.phtml
<?php

// call current category and sub category

$categoryHelper_sub = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category');
$_category  = $block->getCurrentCategory();

$objectManager_sub = $objectManager =
\Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$imagehelper = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');
$category = $objectManager_sub->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category');
$categories_sub =
$category->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter('is_active',
1)->addIdFilter($_category->getChildren())->setOrder('position', 'ASC');?>

<?php if(!empty($categories_sub->getData())){ ?>
<div class="page-products">
        <div class="products wrapper grid products-grid">
                <div class="col-xs-12 abt_head caps">
                        <h2><?php echo $_category->getName(); ?></h2>
                        <p><?php echo $_category->getDescription(); ?></p>
                        <div class="current-image">
                                        <img src="<?php echo $_category->getImageUrl()?>" >
                        </div>
                </div>
                        <?php foreach($categories_sub as $category_sub): ?>
                                <?php $category_sub->getParentId();
                                $categoryobj =
$objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory');
                                $category =
$objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');//get
current category
                        $category_sub->getChildren();?>
                                <div class='submenu'>
                                        <a href="<?php echo
$categoryHelper_sub->getCategoryUrl($category_sub);?>">
                                        <div class='submenu-img'> <img src="<?php echo
$category_sub->getImageUrl()?>" alt="<?php echo
$category_sub->getName()?>"></img>
                                        </div>
                                        <?php //echo $category_sub->getName()?></a>
                                </div>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have create small module for display sub category please check this link.

https://github.com/pratikmage/magento2-subcategory